# Showing recaptcha v2 text only in english

Tags: recaptcha

I am using Google Recaptcha v2 in my site. Clients reported seeing Arabiac, Swedish texts too. How can I force the captcha to be english only.

Thanks and Regards, 
Swapnil Daga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Under JavaScript resource (api.js) parameters:

Parameter and description

**hl** - Forces the widget to render in a specific language. Auto-detects the user's language if unspecified.

so modify your link to incorporate **hl=en** parameter and value as below

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"
    async defer>
</script>
```